# Python - Print message at the end of iterating a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I've got a CSV with some information in and the code will iterate through each line in the CSV, and if the username that's entered matches the value in the line, it will allow the user to log in.

However, I'm not sure how to allow my program to say when their details aren't correct. The "not found" prints out after every iteration rather than at the end of the CSV.

How could I make it so that once it's at the end of the for loop, it says that the details aren't found?

Thanks.

```
username = str(input("Enter your username: "))
password = str(input("Enter your password: "))

file = open("details.csv","r")
print('Details opened')
contents = csv.reader(file)
print('reader established')

for row in contents:
    print('begin loop')
    if username == row[4]:
        print("Username found")
        if password == row[3]:
            print("Password found")
            main()
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution is add variable `is_found` as example:

```
is_found = False

for row in contents:
    print('begin loop')
    if username == row[4]:
        print("Username found")
        if password == row[3]:
            print("Password found")
            main()
            is_found = True

if not is_found:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: @BearBrown your solution too complex for Python ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) and anyway [stop using print for debugging](https://www.loggly.com/blog/4-reasons-a-python-logging-library-is-much-better-than-putting-print-statements-everywhere/)

```
for row in contents:
    print('begin loop')
    if username == row[4]:
        print("Username found")
        if password == row[3]:
            print("Password found")
            main()
            break
else:
    print("not found")
```